# Yii active record can't write but can read

Tags: php, database, activerecord, frameworks, yii

I wanted to create a user registration page but it found out a difficult. I can not write in database but can read from it with no problems. also I am getting no error at all when I want to insert  via Active Error. here is example of what I am doing

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = 'irakli';
    $user->save();
    $this->render('index');
}
```

This code is NOT working but I am getting no error at all.
Please take a note that

```
$record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
$data = $record->id;
$this->render('index', array('data'=>$data));
```

is working correctly.

Comment: The details of your issue is not enough. Did you try to log (e.g weblog) if not you should have a look at it. On the other hand, post model class too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help debug problem.

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = 'irakli';
if (!    $user->save() ) {
    print_r( $user->getErrors() );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. The same was suggested on Yii forum just now, but thank you anyway